# Error in lambda expression syntax

Tags: c++, algorithm, lambda

This code:

```
#include "Backpack.h"
#include <sstream>
#include <algorithm>

int Backpack::getCurrentWeight()
{
    int weight = 0;
    std::for_each(items.begin(),items.end(),[&](std::shared_ptr<PickupItem> item){ //8
        weight +=item->getWeight();
    });
    return weight;
}
```

generates these errors:

```
Backpack.cpp: In member function 'int Backpack::getCurrentWeight()':
Backpack.cpp:8: error: expected primary-expression before '[' token
Backpack.cpp:8: error: expected primary-expression before ']' token
Backpack.cpp:8: error: expected primary-expression before 'item'
```

The project builds on Linux, but on Windows it does not. My Qt version: Qt 4.7.4 for Desktop - MinGW 4.4 (Qt SDK). I added following flag: QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += -std=c++0x

Comment: I don't think it is a problem with the Qt version, but a problem with the compiler version. It looks like it does not support lambda expressions, so it thinks you are trying to use `operator[]` without specifying the object in which you want to use it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your compiler does not support lambda expressions.

Comment: Which compiler do you suggest on Windows?

Comment: @mmvie Newer versions of MinGW support lambdas.

Comment: I installed QT SDK, can I upgrade MinGW by installing latest version to QtSDK/mingw ?

Comment: As I remember CL also support lambdas.